# Show SweetAlert in delete function php

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I'm trying to show the sweet alert in my DELETE FEATURE but sadly my code now is not working I already search for similar feature I see some but it not help me thought. Here is my code

```
 <a id="<?php echo $id;?>" value="<?php echo $id;?>"  name="delete"   onclick="archiveFunction(this.id)">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red"></i></a>
```

And this is my ajax request

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
$('#reloadpage').click(function() {

    location.reload(true);
});
function archiveFunction(id) {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
var form = event.target.form; // storing the form
        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "But you will still be able to retrieve this file.",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    // this is `post` request to the server
    // so you can get the data from $_POST variables, says $_POST['delete'] $_POST['v_id']
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'delete': true, 'id' : id },
        url: 'user_del.php',
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
    swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");

} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
}
```

And this is my archive query . Don't bother about my query I set the status to 0 for me to archive one data and it will go to archive page. I just want to display the SWEET ALERT when I'm deleting the data or archiving it. Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index');
endif;
include("../dist/includes/dbcon.php");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE accounts_at SET status = 0 WHERE id ='$id'")
    or die(mysqli_error());
        if ($result !== false) {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully deleted a account!');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='index'</script>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATED alert is in the wrong spot if you want it to run after the object is officially deleted on the server.

```
function(isConfirm){
 if (isConfirm) {
// this is `post` request to the server
 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'delete': true, 'id' : id },
    url: 'user_del.php',
    success: function(data) { 
       //if you put it here it will run after the file is deleted
      swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");
    }
})
//if you put it here it will run before and even if your file is not deleted
// swal("Updated!", "Your imaginary file has been Deleted.", "success");

} else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
}
```

Open up the develop console in your web browser. Does it give you any errors? 
Do you get any alerts at all?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I replace my old code to your code but it not working too. Even my <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-red"></i> is not clickable. In what part I'm wrong? Please enlighten me.

Comment: what does the browser console say? If you click on it and nothing happens there is probably an error showing up in the console.  https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/how-open-browser-console-view-errors

Comment: well, let's try this. right after 'function archiveFunction(id) {  ' put 'console.log("click event fired");'  If that doesn't show up it means the event is not calling your function.

Comment: I can't call my function thru the ONCLICK event . Do I miss something here?

Comment: Right click on your icon and choose "Inspect Element" (depends on the browser). It should open up a window that will show you what your link looks like to the browser. Take screen shot and post it for more help.

Comment: You can also try adding the click event with javascript $('a[name="delete"]').click..or something similar

Comment: This is my console screenshot . Please click the link: https://imgur.com/a/yQCrLjD

Comment: that little tag that says "event" means your onclick event did. attach.  My guess is you might not have all the console notifications turned on. If you don't want to mess with figuring that out right now, you can use alert() instead. function archiveFunction(id){ alert('I was clicked');  and see what happens.

Comment: Right after that regular alert I'd add the simplest sweet alert. alert("I was clicked"); swal("Simple sweet alert is working");

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function archiveFunction(id) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (!isConfirm) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function () {
                swal("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I already try this but it doesn't work. I can't call my function thru the ONCLICK event